# Submitting Virus Samples Via Email

Tags: virus, avg-antivirus

A friend of mine is investigating a potential false positive detected by AVG. When I go on AVG's website, they ask that false positives be zipped into a zip file and sent via email to virus@avg.com. I'm not really comfortable sending a virus over email from one of my email accounts. Sending viruses over email seems illegal and at the very least should be a violation of the email provider's terms of usage.

Is there any good way that I can submit this suspicious virus to AVG without sending it via email? If not, does anyone have a recommendation for a free email provider whose terms of use allows this sort of message?

Answer (score 1):

Use a an anonymous online e-mail account from google, yahoo or similar.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a false positive, then it should be a perfectly harmless file, right?

Regardless, I would suggest using a free online service, such as Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about detection, you can encrypt the zip file.

I don't think it will be found to be illegal or even questionable to send a file if

1. The recipient specifically requests viruses,
2. You are explicit in the email that the contents are or might be a virus, and
3. The file is not, in fact, malicious.